# Windows Server idle hard disks

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a small windows server at home, which is always on, but doesn't get used very intensively.

In order to prolong the disk life, does Windows Server (2012 R2 in my case) offer any ability to idle disks that are not in use?

Comment: This is one of those things where its entirely your choice. On one hand allowing a drive to stop spinning, means it has to start spinning again, to access the data.  That process while not harmful does not have any benefits either.  On the other hand, HDDs have an expected lifespan, which means spinning could extend the amount of days it is in service (but it does not extend that lifespan) if that makes any sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the Control panel, "Power options", "Change Plan Settings", "Change Advanced Power Settings" you'll find an option where you can turn the harddrives off after a certain amount of idle time.